# Use JavascriptExecutor in Page-Object-Model

Tags: javascript, java, maven, selenium-webdriver, pageobjects

there has been an automation side project I've been working on in my spare time and I've been trying to incorporate JavascriptExecutor into my Page Object Model since some of the portions of the website I picked isn't functioning when clicking on  tag. 
Currently this is how I my code set up in the PageObject class (my superclass for my Page-Object Model):

```
public class PageObject {
    protected Driver driver;
    public Actions act;
    public JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;

    PageObject(Driver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.act = new Actions(driver);
    }
}
```

This is the layout for the Driver class (which implements the WebDriver):

```
public class Driver implements WebDriver {

public WebDriver driver;
String browserName;
public JavascriptExecutor js;

public Driver(String browserName) {
    this.browserName = browserName;
    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./resources/webdrivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        this.js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
    }
    // Below are other if conditions for different browsers.
```

Currently, I'm getting a NullpointerException with js, but I know if I initialize js inside the PageObject constructor, I get hit with a ClassCastException. (I have these classes set up in a Maven Project.)
I've looked around online and this doesn't appear to be a common topic that gets asked and right now, I'm completely stumped on how to solve this or if it's even possible. Has anyone else encountered this situation?

Update: figured out the problem.

```
   public class PageObject {
    protected Driver driver;
    public Actions act;

    PageObject(Driver driver){
        this.driver = driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
        this.act = new Actions(driver);
    }
}

public class Driver implements WebDriver {

public WebDriver driver;
String browserName;
public static JavascriptExecutor js;

public Driver(String browserName) {
    this.browserName = browserName;
    if (browserName.equalsIgnoreCase("chrome")) {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./resources/webdrivers/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver.exe");
        this.driver = new ChromeDriver();
        js = (JavascriptExecutor) this.driver;
    }
    // Below are other if conditions for different browsers.
```

I had to change js into static and then wherever I have a portion of the website where the  are non-clickable, I call on Driver.js to execute whatever command I need for any webpage my framework tests.

Comment: using `this` on a field in the static context is not possible. Your second way of creating `this.js` in the `Driver` constructor is correct. Can you add this code and post its output?: `System.out.println(driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor);`. This check is usually used before casting `WebDriver` to `JavascriptExecutor`. Also make sure you are using the correct imports. Better edit your answer with those included.

Comment: The imports appear to be correct. In the Driver class, the driver instanceof JavascriptExecutor prints "true". In the PageObject, that same code prints "false" since it wasn't initialized inside the constructor. I also solved my NullPointer issue by switching the js to static, removed this and now my other webpages can click on the <a> tags if the click method doesn't work with WebElement or Actions. Thank you for your help.